# Where can I find the positions of the infrared band for phosphorus compounds in general? Specifically sodium hexametaphosphate

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, ir-spectroscopy

Specifically I am looking for the IR of the sodium hexametaphosphate compound.

Comment: Can you elaborate the question a bit, to add more context? And the title should ideally be short, and any additional information is better placed in the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specific for your compound you find at least two public IR spectra, either in KBr:

[image]
([source](https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/landingpage?sdbsno=2983))

or from one of the larger chemical vendors as .pdf

[image]
([source](https://www.sigmaaldrich.com/spectra/ftir/FTIR005059.PDF), Sigma-Aldrich, product number 305553, CAS-RN 68915-31-1)

More generally speaking *for phosphates*, you equally find some related entries in NIST webbook chemistry [here](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Name=*metaphosphate&Units=SI), too.

For IR-spectra in general, beside the [SDBS](https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/cgi-bin/cre_index.cgi) with focus on organic compounds and sources already mentioned, there are three big multi-volume collections: *Aldrich* (equally one large about NMR) which is why frequently chemicals in their online catalogue have a link to either IR or/and NMR spectrum, too. The *Sadtler* collection is equally broad and diverse, organizes the entries by field of application (e.g., pharmaceuticals, forensics).  At least in part Sadtler is electronically available *via* BioRad / KnowItAll, too.  Finally *Hummel*, with emphazis on polymers / plastics.  Because many products of chemical synthesis are characterized by IR spectroscopy, too, you may find them indexed in databases like Reaxys (Elsevier) and Scifinder (American Chemical Society), too.